# Arduino Nano R3 & Deek-Robot datalogging shield

Tags: arduino-uno

Whilst I am much more at home programming PIC ISR's in assembler, I am building a data logger using a DS1307 to interrupt every second to write data to a USB SD card.

There does not appear to be a connection or even a pad from the DS1307 SQW for interrupts and feel I must be missing something, as this would be a remarkable designer/manufacturer oversight?

Comment: what is your question? ... are you asking if it would be a remarkable oversight?

Comment: is it so important to track the real time seconds in your project? using millis() function is not good enough?

Comment: Thanks and no worries.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any official source for information about "Deek-Robot datalogging shield" but what I do find indicates it is the same or similar design as an [Adafruit Datalogging shield](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-data-logger-shield/). The DS1307 (or other RTC) square wave out signal is routed to a through-hole on the interior of the board indicated in this image:

[image: SQ pin indicated]

It does not appear to be routed anywhere else an any of these boards. Note: the picture here is of a board (Current Adafruit logging shield apparently) that uses an NXP RTC that has the same pinout as the DS1307, but uses a different register layout. But in any case places the SQ output on a header in the same basic location. So you would need to solder a header to accept a jumper. Or solder a wire from there to one of the through holes for a digital pin, probably pin 2 or 3 if you're on an UNO (you have tagged) since those are the pins compatible with `attachInterrupt()`

Comment: Thanks, once I put my glasses on I was able to find it.